# clearable textbox

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am trying to create an app with no of clearable textboxes (a textbox with a 'x' inside, on clicking 'x' datas gets cleared in textbox).

I gone thru 2 links [this one](http://jacob4u2.blogspot.in/2010/07/clearable-textbox-for-win-phone-7.html) and [this one](http://silverscratch.blogspot.in/2010/03/watermarked-textbox-part-i.html), it wasnt helpful.

Can any one help to create a function for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure what the exactly problem you are facing. you can achieve this by having a textbox and a roundbutton (coding4fun) in a grid (adjacent columns)

the tap on button clears the textbox. you can even create yourself a nice user control that wraps the code nicely so you can have multiple instances.

Comment: hi dave, i am have big app, instead of writing code for each  clearable textbox ,i like to create a function so that calling the fuction at any space i could create the control.

Comment: thats exactly what user controls are for. you wrap code for the functionality within user control and create instances of it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?

```
        public TextBox CreateTextBox(string defaultText)
        {
            var tb = new TextBox { Text = defaultText };
            tb.GotFocus += new RoutedEventHandler((object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) =>
            {
                if (tb.Text == defaultText)
                    tb.Text = "";
            });

            return tb;
        }
```

Comment: s.but am creating a clearable textbox.how to place a 'x'button inside the textbox using same function that clears the text.????

Comment: Then create a StackPanel(or some kind of container control) and put the TextBox and the Button into that.

Answer (score 0):

You missed out this [Link](http://jacob4u2.blogspot.in/2010/07/clearable-textbox-custom-control.html). It has a custom control "ClearableTextbox" which may suit your requirements.

You can download the [source code](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9590085/BlogFiles/ClearableTextBox.zip) which includes the dll file as well.

Include a reference to that dll in your project and then add the following line in the xaml page,

```
xmlns:clrtb="clr-namespace:ClearableTextBox;assembly=ClearableTextBox"
```

And then you can use the textbox something like,

```
<clrtb:ClearableTextBox Width="300" Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

As the source code is available, you can make some modifications to it, so that it fits your requirements

**UPDATE:**

Alternately, I found this great control which makes your task easy:

[PhoneTextBox](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-Toolkit-PhoneTextBox-in-depth) in [SilverlightWP7 toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Full Disclosure: I work at Telerik and our TextBox has this functionality built in: 
http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls.aspx